# Mysql for c#. Объектная модель как для Sqlite

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных

У меня установлен Mysql сервер и Mysql Workbench. На сервере уже есть готовая база данных. Есть ли способы подключения и работы с бд как при работе с sqllite? То есть, чтобы без sql кода, а просто объектами.

Comment: Есть такие способы. Можно использовать любую ORM: EntityFramework, Linq2DB, Dapper и другие.

Comment: А можно ссылку в студию по установке  EntityFramework?

Answer (score 0):

Лично я пользуюсь PetaPoco для такой же задачи. Ставить с ню-гет пакеджа.
Тем более, что база уже создана.

Примеры кода пета-поко есть сдесь:

https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco

С энтити прийдется разбиратся, кроме того он достаточно медленный. Если захочешь его -- ставить точно так же с нюгет-пакеджа.